# android command takes a long time to respond after updating Android SDK to latest version(android-20)

Tags: android, windows, sdk

I downloaded the latest sdk from https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=i#download and extracted it to a folder.I run the command "android" on my command prompt and the sdk manager takes like 10 minutes to pop up.Anybody else faced this issue?Also,is there a conflict between the jdk version and latest android sdk?I tried using Java 7 ans well as 8,but no resolution yet.

Comment: android.exe? do you mean eclipse?

Comment: \EclipseAndroid\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platforms\android-20\android.jar

Comment: I am running Windows 7 and have this very android.jar on my class path